# How to extract image and Texts from a url in android

Tags: android, sharing

I have created an android app for sharing contents from web browser. I have used intents for receiving the data from the Web Browser. It only gives me text/plain (url only) data. How can I display the article image and the text in the receiving page?

Comment: please add your code so people can help you

Comment: downloading it from the url? is that what your looking for?

Comment: Yes @Nanco. I am getting the url now. How can I display the content of the page briefly for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the implicit intent data, just run the async task or you can use Volley library to load the data from the url. See this example,

```
    //Implicit Intent Data onActivityResult

  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       String url = data.getData().toString();

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);


    // Retrieves an image specified by the URL, displays it in the UI.
    ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(url,
        new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Bitmap bitmap) {
                mImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }, 0, 0, null,
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                mImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_load_error);
            }
        });
                queue.add(request);
                    }
```